# maven settings custom properties

Tags: maven, build, pom.xml

I'm completely new to Maven.  I'm trying to set up a new project such that it doesn't require 20 page long word docs with screenshots to set it up.  I've got developers on Macs and PCs, so I need to be able to customize the catalina.home directory as I can't just impose a standard location.  I thought I'd do it in the ~/.m2/settings.xml file with the following:

```
<profile>
  <id>my-site-dev</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
  <properties>
    <catalina.home>/path/to/apache-tomcat</catalina.home>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

However, the documentation here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html#Profile_Pitfalls seems to indicate that what I'm trying to accomplish is a bad idea.  What's the official way of accomplishing this so that in my pom.xml I can just reference ${catalina.home}?

And now that I've declared my profile with an id, can I fail the build if my pom.xml can't load the profile "my-site-dev"?  I'd like to get that <activeByDefault> out of the settings.xml if at all possible.  I don't want to interfere with their global settings for no reason, I'd like to keep as much of it self contained as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `activeByDefault`, since it will cloak all other profiles:

Here is what you should use:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>path-to-catalina.home-linux</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>linux</family>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <catalina.home>...</catalina.home>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>path-to-catalina.home-mac</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>mac</family>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <catalina.home>...</catalina.home>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>path-to-catalina.home-windows</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>windows</family>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <catalina.home>...</catalina.home>           
           </properties>
     </profile>
```

Comment: Thanks, now that I understand what's going on, that's about perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a profile in your pom that gets activated based on os.

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <os>
        ...
```

What are you doing that require catalina.home?

If you're doing deployment to an app server with maven, you are already outside of the 'consistent, portable build' rule set - and outside of the main use case / best practices for maven.

Not that you shouldn't do it - as it's convenient. Just make sure to separate your build projects from the deployment projects.

Comment: if I'm outside of the consistent portable build rule set, then why is there a default mvn deploy target?  I'd like for developers to be able to type mvn deploy, have all tests run, compile and build the war, and deploy it locally so they can then run UATs (if there's a better way, I'm open to that as well).

Comment: mvn deploy means "deploy built artifact (generally a .war file)" to a maven repository so other projects can depend on it without having to build it. It has nothing to do with application deployment. Also, have you looked at http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/?